# assembly reg_reg or reg_immediate

Tags: performance, arm, instructions, register-transfer-level

executed on the same cpu architecure, which of these needs less clock cycles (#RTL)

```
add dest_reg, src1_reg, src2_reg   // #1

add dest_reg, src1_reg, imm_val    // #2
```

I mean even constants need to be fetched from registers, no?
thank U

Comment: Just because you postulate that more work needs to be done doesn't mean it takes extra clocks.  Even in a synchronous system things are done in parallel and multiple actions can happen in a single clock cycle.  The ARM 'imm_val' is encoded in the instruction, so the act of fetching the instruction will have it available; the register is effectively zero wait state memory with its own bus.  The 'imm_val' will probably take **less energy**.  The will almost always be the same, unless 'reg2' is the result of a multiply or some other blocking/multi-cycle instruction (not comparable to 'imm_val').

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with your hardware reference manual. There's a chance (like thumb2) the constant will be encoded inside the instruction, so in some cases, no the constant doesn't need to be fetched.

Comment: I am dealing with and x86 processor, but I checked the manual, Imm_vals are encoded in the opCode.  Thank U

Comment: Why did you tag the question as `arm` then? I'm glad you found your answer.